# Downloading a web page. OK with wget, fails with java

Tags: java, url, networking, wget

I'm trying to download the following page: http://structureddata.wikispaces.com/Test

**wget** without any option fails:

```
wget "http://structureddata.wikispaces.com/Test"
(...) connect to session.wikispaces.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'
```

with --no-check-certificate, it works

```
wget --no-check-certificate "http://structureddata.wikispaces.com/Test"
grep Hello Test
 Hello World
```

Now, i would like to download the same URL with java, but the following simple program:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Test
        {
        public static void main(String args[])
                {
                int c;
                try
                        {
                        InputStream in=new URL("http://structureddata.wikispaces.com/Test").openStream();
                        while((c=in.read())!=-1) System.out.print((char)c);
                        in.close();
                        }
                catch(Throwable err)
                        {
                        err.printStackTrace();
                        }
                }
        }
```

returns nothing

what should I do to download the page with java ?

Many thanks,

Ppierre

Comment: There is something strange : the error indicates you are using https which is inconsistent with the URL given. I cannot reproduce the message from wget. Is there a proxy server involved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Java URL interface is fairly low-level; it does not automatically do things like follow redirects.  Your code above is getting no content to print out because there is none.

By doing something like the below, you'll see that what you are getting is an HTTP 302 response -- a redirect.

```
  URL url = new URL("http://structureddata.wikispaces.com/Test");

  URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
  Map<String, List<String>> headers = urlConnection.getHeaderFields();
  Set<Map.Entry<String, List<String>>> entrySet = headers.entrySet();
  for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : entrySet) {
    String headerName = entry.getKey();
    System.out.println("Header Name:" + headerName);
    List<String> headerValues = entry.getValue();
    for (String value : headerValues) {
      System.out.print("Header value:" + value);
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
  }
```

I'd suggest using a library like [HTTPClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) which will handle more of the protocol for you.

(credit where it is due:  Copied the above code from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0320__Network/URLConnectionopenStreamismorepowerfulthanURLopenStream.htm).)

Comment: It does automatically follow redirects, only not if it concerns a different scheme. Check yourself by `((HttpURLConnection) urlConnection).getFollowRedirects()`.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at [commons-httpclient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/tutorial.html), this code returns the page no problem

```
final HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
final GetMethod method = new GetMethod("http://structureddata.wikispaces.com/Test");
try {
    if (HttpStatus.SC_OK == client.executeMethod(method)) {
        System.out.println(IOUtils.toString(method.getResponseBodyAsStream()));
    } else {
        throw new IOException("Unable to load page, error " + method.getStatusLine());
    }
} finally {
    method.releaseConnection();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that it returns a `302` redirect response to a `https` url. Since the initial request is `http` and the target is `https`, the `URLConnection` won't automatically follow the redirect (it will however do when the target is using the same scheme).

After some observation I concluded that it goes to `https` to request some authentication token which in turn get redirected to a `http` url again with the authentication token as request parameter. So, it should be following redirects from `http` to `https` and then `http` with the actual page content.

The following works here.

```
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    // First request.
    URLConnection connection = new URL("http://structureddata.wikispaces.com/Test").openConnection();

    // Go to the redirected https page to obtain authentication token.
    connection = new URL(connection.getHeaderField("location")).openConnection();

    // Re-request the http page with the authentication token.
    connection = new URL(connection.getHeaderField("location")).openConnection();

    // Show page.
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        for (String line; ((line = reader.readLine()) != null);) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } finally {
        if (reader != null) try { reader.close(); } catch (IOException ignore) {}
    }
}
```

I however do agree that [Commons HttpComponents Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client/) is a better tool for the job.